# GAE: how to make createLoginURL point to a generic google login while still restricting logins to a specific domain and its sub-domains?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, dns

I have a GAE app where I need users to log in from domain.com as well as sub.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, etc. I have created an app that restricts users to log in from domain.com, but then when i use the code:

```
<a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI()) %>">Sign in</a>
```

Users are taken to a login page that restricts entry to ***_*__**@domain.com and therefore does not allow users at sub.domain.com to enter in their emails and passwords to log in.

How can I go about making this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is to recreate the application (yes, with a different name -- arg!) and to choose the last authentication option: OpenID. But this does mean that you need to put code in your app to ensure the people logging in are the ones you want to log in!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created your app with authentication set to only allow users on 'domain.com'. You need to create a new app set to use Google Account authentication, which will allow any user with a Google account to log in. Then, you can restrict access in software based on their domain.

Comment: I was hoping sub domains would be considered a part of the parent domain. Sounds like I just have to kill and recreate the app.

Comment: And another gotcha. If I recreate the app to allow all google users to access it I cannot reuse the app name... Unless someone knows a way around that??

Comment: @MindWire You can file a production issue to request the old App ID be aliased to the new one.